# Como resolver error 503

Tags: php5, https

He creado una app web para subir archivos a un servidor, el problema es que no me deja subir archivos porque me esta marcando el error 503, la verdad no se cual sea el problema:

Mi código es este:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(3600);

$path = '../archivos/';

//comprobamos que sea una petición ajax
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') 
{
    //obtenemos la extesion del el archivo a subir
    
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['archivo']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
     
    $nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name']; 
     
    $path = $path.$nombre.".".$ext;
     
    //comprobamos si el archivo ha subido
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'], $path))
    {
       echo 1;
    }
    else
      echo 0;
}else{
    echo 0;
}
?>
```

Comment: El error 503 indica que el servidor no está listo para manejar la solicitud. 
Las causas más comunes son que el servidor esté apagado por mantenimiento o esté sobrecargado.

Comment: Pero como puedo saber cual es el problema?? En modo local funciona bien pero en linea no quiere